# open 2 jar files on linux command

Tags: java, linux, command-line, gnome-terminal

I need to open run two jar applications in the same time

I know that to run a jar file you have to type

```
java -jar app1.jar
```

but  I need to terminate the current process to run

```
java -jar app2.jar
```

How can I open app2 without closing app1 ?

Comment: open in a separate window and exeucte java -jar command with your own jar file.. If you open two windows two java process will be created..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run one, push it into the background, and then run the other.

Run the first command, press `ctrl-z` and then type `bg`.

This runs the command in the background, leaving your command line available for you to call you next command.

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/05/unix-background-job/

Answer (score 2):

Execute this bash command

```
( java -jar app1.jar ) &
( java -jar app2.jar )
```

The commands will execute in parallel subshells

Comment: The parentheses are not necessary